# Add object to NSMutableArray in another class

Tags: ios, properties, nsmutablearray

Hi I have a grouped tableview the first section contains a list of emails and the second section just has two rows which are add email manually and select email from contacts.

The log in ManualEmail.m keeps logging 0 for the count and the array in EmailViewController is never modified, but I can't figure out what's wrong

This is my current set up

**EmailViewController.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSMutableArray *dataArray;
```

**EmailViewController.m**

```
@synthesize dataArray;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *listItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];
    [listItems addObject:[ObjectArrays productWithType:@"test" Eemail:@"test@website.com" Eselected:YES]];
    NSDictionary *firstItemsArrayDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:listItems forKey:@"data"];
    [dataArray addObject:firstItemsArrayDict];
    NSArray *secondItemsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Add Email Address From Contacts", @"Add Email Address Manually", nil];
    NSDictionary *secondItemsArrayDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:secondItemsArray forKey:@"data"];
    [dataArray addObject:secondItemsArrayDict];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

**ManualEmail.m**

```
    EmailViewController *emailPVC = [[EmailViewController alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [emailPVC.dataArray objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSMutableArray *emailArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array];
    [emailArray addObject:[ObjectArrays productWithType:name.text Eemail:email.text Eselected:YES]];
    [emailPVC.dataArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    NSDictionary *firstItemsArrayDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:emailArray forKey:@"data"];
    [emailPVC.dataArray insertObject:firstItemsArrayDict atIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%d", [emailPVC.dataArray count]);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why is the log returning 0 and why am I unable to modify the array from ManualEmail.m

Answer (score 0):

In ManualEmail.m, you're creating the `EmailViewController` in code. But you aren't ever calling anything that would call its `-viewDidLoad` method, so the `dataArray` isn't ever getting created or filled out. You need to call `emailPVC.view = <some view you created>;` in order for `-viewDidLoad` to get called.

Comment: Does it not matter that ManualEmail can only be called from EmailViewController meaning EmailViewController is called and then ManualEmail is pushed from there so EmailViewController viewDidLoad was called when it first opened

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint in `-viewDidLoad` to ensure that it's getting called? That would tell you better than any conjecture from me.

Comment: It's definitely called when EmailViewController is and the array is initialized then but then the manualemail is pushed to the navigation stack and the array then is apparently empty it's got me confused since the property shouldn't be reset at any point